# How to increment Index of type Date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to increment the index by 1 for the following array:

```
Date          High
2017-02-01    253.20 
2017-02-02    252.42
2017-02-03    252.18
2017-02-06    257.82
2017-02-07    260.00
```

I know that we can increment date by using`timedelta(days=1)` but this will generate a date which my array may not have.
So is there any way to increment the index?

and after incrementing, how can i get the value for that incremented index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df.index = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='D')
print (df)
              High
Date              
2017-02-02  253.20
2017-02-03  252.42
2017-02-04  252.18
2017-02-07  257.82
2017-02-08  260.00
```

Or is possible use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df = df.shift(1, freq='D')
print (df)
              High
Date              
2017-02-02  253.20
2017-02-03  252.42
2017-02-04  252.18
2017-02-07  257.82
2017-02-08  260.00
```

EDIT:

For replace `DatetimeIndex` is possible use `rename` by `dict`:

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime('2017-02-03')
d2 = d1 + pd.to_timedelta(5, unit='D')
df = df.rename(index={d1:d2})
print (df)
              High
Date              
2017-02-01  253.20
2017-02-02  252.42
2017-02-08  252.18
2017-02-06  257.82
2017-02-07  260.00
```

For select 3. index value:

```
d1 = df.index[2]
d2 = d1 + pd.to_timedelta(5, unit='D')
df = df.rename(index={d1:d2})
print (df)
              High
Date              
2017-02-01  253.20
2017-02-02  252.42
2017-02-08  252.18
2017-02-06  257.82
2017-02-07  260.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but i ran into next problem. which is, if i want to increment a specific index by 5 days, like the 3rd index(2017-02-04) how do i increment from that particular index?

Comment: You answered what i asked correctly, but my mistake, i will ask my question more specifically soon.